# How to organise resources in web application URL structure

Tags: php, rest, url, url-rewriting, url-routing

## Current situation

I am developing an **Online Order Management** system application with PHP and I need to design REST resource mappings through URL scheme.

I have typical resources:

- **Customer** (has Orders)
- **Order** (has Tickets)
- **Ticket** (has Messages)
- **Message**

I am thinking of something like this:

1. **Customer profile:**

   ```
    example.com/customers/{customer-ID}
   ```
2. **Orders for {customer-ID}:**

   ```
    example.com/customers/{customer-ID}/orders
   ```
3. **Tickets for {order-ID}:**

   ```
    example.com/customers/{customer-ID}/orders/{order-ID}/tickets
   ```
4. **Messages for {ticket-ID}**

   ```
    example.com/customers/{customer-ID}/orders/{order-ID}/tickets/{ticket-ID}/messages
   ```

## Findings

One day of googling and I found these qutoes:

1. > Namespacing features behind the username like
   >
   > ```
   > example.com/{username}/followers
   > ```
   >
   > are great solutions for **public features** that belong to each user individually.
2. > Private things, such as account settings, **should never be namespaced behind the username**, and should just appear after `/account` or `/settings`.
3. > It's best to keep the base resource URLs as lean as possible. **Filters**, **sorting** requirements, advanced **searching** and **pagination** can all be implemented as **query parameters**.
4. > A query string should be treated as an **optional addition** to the page; the URL should work to produce a valid and useful page even when it’s removed.
5. > In a good, **hackable URL**, a human can adjust or remove parts of the path and get expected results from your site. They give your visitors better orientation around your pages, and enable them to easily move up levels.
6. > By **embedding a unique ID early on in your path**, you can have long, fully descriptive URLs when needed but still enjoy the reliability of shorter URLs and the speed of ID lookups.
7. > **Adding multiple keywords to URLs** may help with SEO, but it will confuse your users. Also, you’ll quickly run the risk of being marked as a keyword spammer.

## Questions

- Am I doing things wrong?
- Shall I avoid namespacing **customers**, **orders**, **tickets** and **messages**?
- Does it have any real major security concern?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

If all the relationships you describe are one to many (not many-to-many) than I don't really see what you gain by having URL's that, for example, contain a customer id, when the order id is known.  It is redundant information, and will provide no additional useful information in your controllers.

In fact it may cause MORE complexity than desired, as now you have to deal with cases where the might be a customer to order id mismatch.  You now have to check all those conditions and return a bad request response if those bad conditions occur.  Why add that overhead?

Perhaps just:

Customer profile:

```
example.com/customers/{customer-ID}
```

Orders for {customer-ID}:

```
example.com/customers/{customer-ID}/orders
```

Tickets for {order-ID}:

```
example.com/orders/{order-ID}/tickets
```

Messages for {ticket-ID}

```
example.com/tickets/{ticket-ID}/messages
```

If however you had a many-to-many relationship, this might change.  Say for example that a customer could enter a single ticket that covers multiple orders (which means the tickets are now more related to the customer than to the order itself), then you might need URL's like the following in addition to those shown above:

See all orders for a given ticket:

```
example.com/tickets/{ticket-ID}/orders
```

See all tickets for a customer:

```
example.com/customer/{customer-ID}/tickets
```

Comment: In ur suggested scheme, what is the difference between `example.com/customers/{customer-ID}/orders` and `example.com/orders`?

Comment: @Trix `/orders` would probably list all orders whereas `/customers/{customer-ID}/orders` would list all order for that customer ID.

Comment: Then, when a customer visits `/orders` what is (s)he supposed to see? An **Access denied!** message?!

Comment: @Trix That is up to you to determine.  If you have a use case for an end user (as opposed to admin user) to see a full list of orders, then you can return the full list.  If you don't have an appropriate use case for an edn user there, your authorization on this method, should cause an appropriate 4XX or 5XX series response to be returned.

Comment: Tnx, but in argue to your suggestion, what is the matter with using only `/orders` & `/orders/{order-ID}` and putting access levels into work? There we may show any user only her/his related content

Comment: @Trix I would assume you would have a base `/orders/{order-ID}` functionality (though I didn't note it above). As typically with RESTful services there are always ways to get a specific resource of a given type.  I think you need to understand all the call patterns used in this service (as also noted by @MaksymStrukov) and which call patterns will be used by which type of users in order to really get to final strategy  You do already have proposed a `/customers/{customer-ID}/orders` URL which would give you all orders for a customer.

Comment: @Trix To continue my comment... Typically, in RESTful services you would not use authorization as a mechanism for filtering a result set.  You use authorization to allow access to certain routes in your application.  For that reason, I would not suggest doing something like using `/orders` in combination with authorization data to filter the result set of orders to those only associated to the end customer.  That is what the relational information in your database is for.

Comment: Thanks but I do not plan to implement a RESTful service. It is a web application and it has user interface.

Comment: @Trix Service or not, it looks like you are basically trying to approach this using a RESTful URL routing strategy. You will need some mechanism to parse the provided URL and to route the request to an appropriate piece of logic for rendering. Typically this sort of mechanism also looks at authorization at a route level to make determination on denying the request before ever even handling it off to page rendering logic. I would think you would want to seperate this authorization mechanism from the row filtering mechanisms that would live within your page rendering logic.

Answer (score 0):

> Am I doing things wrong?

It depends. You seem to be on the right track but you would better decide what functionality your service should provide first. Otherwise you might end up with an infinite number of url(resources) to implement. For example, if you need to expose a list of orders across all client you will want to have `example.com/orders` resource with query string parameters to specify search criteria. Otherwise, one will have to query all clients first and then in a loop send requests to `example.com/customers/{customer-ID}/orders` to get all orders across all client.
So first think what functionality your service need to expose and then design the resources for it.

> Does it have any real major security concern?

It has nothing to do with url(resources) design. Authentication and authorization info usually goes in the http headers.

Also please consider adding versioning info to your urls. It turns out to be super helpful when you have to support several versions of your services

```
example.com/v1/customers/{customer-ID}/orders
```

or

```
v1.example.com/customers/{customer-ID}/orders
```

etc.

Lastly, if you are going to support multiple representation for a resource, for example, you might return the clients list as JSON, XML, HTML, etc. it's a good practice to specify it in the url as well. So decide on your default representation format and expose it as `example.com/customers` and then add format info to the end of the url if you support others

```
example.com/customers.xml
```

or

```
example.com/customers.html
```

etc.

Hope it helps!

> I think including IDs in URL may not be a good practice

Well, there are two main approaches and both have it cons and prons. The first one is using names or short resource desciption instead of IDs. For example, instead of client id you can use its name, `example.com/customers/amazon`, where `amazon` is your client name. Another good example of the approach is news sites, if you navigate through `cnn.com` you will see each article url contains article title `http://edition.cnn.com/2016/06/10/middleeast/israel-tel-aviv-shooting/index.html`  - "Tel Aviv suspect discovered hiding in home of off-duty cop"

This is great from SEO perspective and the urls become more descriptive and human friendly. But if you have to change your customer name it should change the url and there's a huge risk of breaking clients. Besides there's a lot of things to keep in mind while implementing the approach:

- You should properly validate customer names so they are ok to be added to an url
- You should either disallow changing customer name or properly handle it by returning 301 ("Moved permanently") and specifying the new url in the Location header so that the client is aware of the new url
- etc.

The main advantage of IDs approach is that urls are always static and you don't have to bother about the implementation stuff above.

Both approaches are valid from REST perspective so it's up to you to decide

Comment: **So first think what functionality your service need to expose and then design the resources for it.** : Customers have Orders which in turn may have Tickets with each Ticket having multiple Messages. functionality is obvious as customer should be able to submit orders. submit tickets on their orders and add messages to their tickets

Comment: @Trix Yeah, but you might have admins who might need to query orders across all clients as described in my answer, there might be other cases as Mike described. It's just an advice so you don't miss anything. If what you specified above is all what you service should expose then you are on the rright track as I said in my answer

Comment: Thanks but, that is obvious that any application needs some admin stuff. I want to know if exposing resource as such, is a good practice or not, supported with convincing evidence

Comment: @Trix What exactly do you mean by "exposing resource as such"? Do you mean my example with getting order with and without customer id in the url?

Comment: There is no real difference between `ID` and `Title`. both need to be checked at routing level. Also blog posts and news items are public resources, while customer orders are not. I think you have misunderstandings about my question.

Comment: @Trix I don't think the problem is ID.  So what if a non-authorized used tries to access a user profile at `/customer/{id}`?  If you have proper authenticatoin and authorization in place, you could have the service form an appropriate 4XX or 5XX HTML response code and deny access to that resource.  If you are worried about a user guessing at a basic integer ID, then you can also consider using a GUID type of field where you have a unique (typically alphanumeric) string that is generated for each customer.  This makes guessing at the GUID much more difficult.

Comment: @MikeBrant That's the point, and I want to know what is behind **Findings #2** in my question.